# Error compiling OSL (Open Shading Language), missing OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS

Tags: c++, cmake

I am unable to compile OSL following their instructions here: 
https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/INSTALL.md

The error complains that is missing an environment variable OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS. I tried building OpenImageIO myself or using vcpkg. So I've set all the other missing vars (e.g. OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARIES)
If I want to set that OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS, where it should point at?
Also why it says it did find the variable but it also say "found
  suitable version "2.1.0", minimum required is "1.8.5"" ?

Here is the error I get when building OSL (I am on Mac):

```
-- Building OSL 1.11.0
-- CMake version is 3.13.3
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:20 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Project build dir   = /Users/simionnacu/Desktop/TestingGrounds/osl/build/macosx
-- Project install dir = /Users/simionnacu/Desktop/TestingGrounds/osl/dist/macosx
-- platform = macosx
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID is AppleClang
-- Building for C++11
-- Setting Namespace to: OSL_v1_11
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenImageIO (missing: OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS) (found
  suitable version "2.1.0", minimum required is "1.8.5")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  src/cmake/modules/FindOpenImageIO.cmake:79 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/cmake/externalpackages.cmake:58 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:133 (include)
```

**edit**: added an image of my env variable and folder tree, based on @Tsyvarev answer
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is script [src/cmake/modules/FindOpenImageIO.cmake](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/cmake/modules/FindOpenImageIO.cmake) which behaves in **unusual** manner:

If it **fails** to find a library at the **first time** `cmake` is run, then it **will fail** all **futher** invocations of `cmake`, whenever environment settings become correct or not.

The only way for make it succeed after the first fail is to remove CMake cache file (`CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory).

---

Usually `FindXXX.cmake` are written so, that if the library **hasn't been found** for the **first time** `cmake` is run, one may adjust environment setting and **re-run** `cmake` for try to **search** the library **again**. CMake commands `find_library`, `find_path` and similar perfectly support such behavior.

---

The script `FindOpenImageIO.cmake` uses

```
find_library(OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY ...)
```

for find `OpenImageIO` library, and then extracts directory part of the library file into another variable `OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS`:

```
get_filename_component (OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS "${OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY}" DIRECTORY CACHE)
```

But it **caches** the result of such extraction (because of `CACHE` option), so if the library hasn't been found for the first time, the variable `OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS` becomes **empty** and **will never been rewriting** again (as it is cached). Emptiness of the variable is treated by the script that "library not found".

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
Could NOT find OpenImageIO (missing: OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS) (found
  suitable version "2.1.0", minimum required is "1.8.5")
```

means that CMake has found OpenImageIO *headers*, has detected version (2.1.0) from them, but has been unable to find *libraries*.

Given error message tells **nothing** about **environment variables** setting, `OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY_DIRS` is a **CMake variable** used by the script.

But if you open [src/cmake/modules/FindOpenImageIO.cmake](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/cmake/modules/FindOpenImageIO.cmake) script, which is listed in the CMake call trace, you may find a way to hint it about your installation of OpenImageIO:

```
# Special inputs:
#   OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR - custom "prefix" location of OIIO installation
#                          (expecting bin, lib, include subdirectories)
```

That is, you may set `OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR` **environment** variable to the installation path of your OpenImageIO library. As noted in the comment, this installation path expects to contain `bin/`, `lib/` and `include/` subdirectories. In the `lib/` subdirectory it should be `OpenImageIO` library file (with appropriate prefix and suffix).

Comment: I've added to the question a screenshot of my .bash_profile and the tree structure of the oiio that I've compiled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hm, assuming variable `OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR`'s set in the `.bash_profile` is actually used, your setup should work. I don't know how to debug `find_library` call (which actually searches for the library and which fails in your case). You may check value of `OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR` (it is stored in `CMakeCache.txt` file located in the build directory). Is this value corresponds to value of `OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR` variable?

Comment: This is the value I have in CMakeCache.txt:
OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/Users/simionnacu/Desktop/TestingGrounds/oiio/dist/macosx/include
It points to include dir, but in the same directory as OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR

Comment: I fixed it! Thx for the help. Basically you mentioned CmakeCache.txt and after going through the lines I realized that this is a cache, so I nuked (make nuke) and then the library compiled. I'm sure that's a rookie mistake. Please add to you answer a mention about CMakeCache.txt and make nuke and I'll accept it as an aswer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, removing `CMakeCache.txt` is a universal "*try that in case of any problem*", like a resetting a PC. Whenever you have a problems with CMake and want to ask someone to help, try to remove `CMakeCache.txt` and run `cmake` again. Nevertheless, I have added the another answer describing what is wrong with that cache (and the script).